# How to get back filename string from file variable in VHDL?

Tags: vhdl

I would like to make a VHDL procedure that closes and opens a file again. Although the procedure would do other things as well, this operation essentially rewinds the file to the beginning.

However, I'm not finding a way to get back to the filename from the file handle.

eg:

```
process 
    procedure close_and_open(file F : text) is
    begin
        file_close(F);
        file_open(F, "HERE_LIES_THE_PROBLEM", read_mode);
    end procedure
    file Fi : text;
begin 
    file_open(Fi, "example_file.txt", read_mode);
    close_and_open(Fi);
    wait;
end process;
```

It seems that Fi'simple_name, instance_name and path_name only refer to the name "Fi" in this case, not the name of the file itself. Naturally, it would be possible to pass the filename as second argument, but it this case it would not be very straight-forward (filenames have run-time generated elements).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your 'file handle' handle in your example is a string literal.

IEEE Std 1076-2008 5.5.2 File operations depend on IEEE Std 1003.1-2004 Portable Operating System Interface (POSIX) - see Annex J. There is no 1003.1 POSIX way to recover the pathname from a file descriptor (represented in VHDL by the FILE object).

In your code there is no way to recover the file logical name from a file declaration or external_name from a file_open procedure when supplied by a literal string expression. There's no named object to evaluate.

You can manipulate a string expression at run time by allocating it's value to an object  of an access type of type string. This provides an object name that denotes a string object.

Leaving the file name argument out of your procedure call is a scope and visibility declaration order exercise due to variable class of an object of an access type. The value of the denoted object is accessed by selected name with the suffix **all** (8.3 Selected names paragraph 5).

Constructing a [Minimal Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve):

```
use std.textio.all;

entity close_open is
end entity;

architecture foo of close_open is

begin 
NOTLABELED:
    process
        type filename is access string;                 -- ADDED 
        variable file_name: filename;                   -- ADDED
        procedure close_and_open(file F : text) is
        begin                                           -- ADDED
            file_close(F);
            -- file_open(F, "HERE_LIES_THE_PROBLEM", read_mode);
            file_open(F, file_name.all, read_mode);     -- CHANGED 
        end procedure;
        file Fi : text;
    begin
        file_name := new string'("example_file.txt");   -- ADDED
        -- file_open(Fi, "example_file.txt", read_mode);
        file_open(Fi, file_name.all, read_mode);        -- CHANGED
        close_and_open(Fi);
        wait;                                           -- ADDED
    end process;

end architecture;
```

There's a declaration order dependency between the access type declaration, the declaration of a variable of the access type and the procedure body.

This example analyzes, elaborates and runs (which requires the file_name be capable of being opened for read).

A wait statement has been added to prevent the process from opening and closing the file without end. There was also a missing begin in your procedure body.

Comment: Thanks, so I conclude there is no direct way, but the file_name must be dragged along. I thought I tried your method already, without success - ended up making a record container with access string, but your example works without that. I also added missing begin and wait so the example is more complete.

Comment: VHDL-2017 will add [more operations on files](http://www.eda-twiki.org/cgi-bin/view.cgi/P1076/TopLCS2016_006a) like seeking and rewinding the read/write pointer. It also brings a [directory API](http://www.eda-twiki.org/cgi-bin/view.cgi/P1076/TopLCS2016_006c).

Comment: You're jumping the gun proselytizing, your revision isn't approved or implemented yet. There's one almost compliant -2008 implementation and no close second place, not to mention abysmal synthesis support.